# Function works for the normal <li> but doesn't work for the ones created by script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, frontend

Here is a html of the site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Login Page</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loginStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="login">
    <input type="text" value="Please, give us your name" id="name">
    <h3 id="name_txt">Log in</h3>
    <h4 id="pilot_txt">Choose your pilot.</h4>
    <ul id="pilots">
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="loginScript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is **loginScript.js** :

```
var uriPilots = '../api/pilots';


$("ul#pilots li").click(function(){
        var t = $(this).text();
        $.cookie("pilot", t);
        $("#pilot_txt").text(t);
    })


$(document).ready(function () {
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.getJSON(uriPilots)
      .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          // Add a list item for the product.
          $('<li>', { text: formatItemProduct(item) }).appendTo('#pilots');
        });
      });
});

function formatItemProduct(item) {
  return item.Name;
}
```

Now, the problem is with the first function. It is supposed to, when user clicks on the `<li>` element, which is loaded from server in second function, create a cookie that stores the text of the `<li>` that was clicked (I change the text of `"#pilot_txt"` only to be able to check easier if it works).

The funny thing is that everything works perfectly if I add a `<li>` element by hand, but for the ones loaded from server it doesn't.

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** when you deal with fresh DOM generated by javascript :

```
$('body').on('click', "ul#pilots li", function(){
    var t = $(this).text();
    $.cookie("pilot", t);
    $("#pilot_txt").text(t);
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should also bind the event with the parent of that element, i.e ul#pilot in your case.

```
$('ul#pilots').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var t = $(this).text();
    $.cookie("pilot", t);
    $("#pilot_txt").text(t);});
```

Comment: In the case of parent loaded dynamically, we need to attach event handler to the body or one of the static parent. Another alternative of this problem is to attach event handler every-time when element appended i.e.
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON(uriPilots)
      .done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          $('<li>', { text: formatItemProduct(item) }).appendTo('#pilots');
        });
  $("ul#pilots li").click(function(){
   var t = $(this).text();
   $.cookie("pilot", t);
   $("#pilot_txt").text(t);
  });
      });
});

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation

```
$('body').on('click', "ul#pilots li", function () {
    var t = $(this).text(); $.cookie("pilot", t);
    ("#pilot_txt").text(t);
})
```